# ARM Cortex-M memory access

Tags: c, memory, arm, interrupt, cortex-m

From [Cortex-M0+ Devices Generic User Guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0497a/BABBGBEC.html) regarding memory regions-

> 2.2.1. Memory regions, types and attributes
>
> **Strongly-ordered**:
>
> The processor preserves transaction order relative to all other transactions.

And-

> Address range:
> **0xE0000000- 0xE00FFFFF**
>
> Memory region: Private Peripheral Bus
>
> Memory type: **Strongly- ordered**
>
> Description: This region includes the NVIC, System timer, and System Control
> Block. Only word accesses can be used in this region.

Now, From [CMSIS documentation](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/Core_A/html/group__CMSIS__Core__InstructionInterface.html)-

> #define __DMB()
>
> Ensures the apparent order of the explicit memory operations before
> and after the instruction, without ensuring their completion.

Based on the information above, it seems that in a code that accesses memory address range of `0xE0000000- 0xE00FFFFF` for example, the `NVIC` controller and the `SysTick` configuration registers, I do not need to use `__DMB` as it is actually performed by hw.

So, for example, if we look at `__NVIC_EnableIRQ`-

```
/**
 \brief   Enable Interrupt
 \details Enables a device specific interrupt in the NVIC interrupt controller.
 \param [in]    IRQn  Device specific interrupt number.
 \note    IRQn must not be negative.
 */
__STATIC_INLINE void __NVIC_EnableIRQ(IRQn_Type IRQn)
{
    if ((int32_t)(IRQn) >= 0)
    {
        NVIC->ISER[0U] = (uint32_t)(1UL << (((uint32_t)(int32_t)IRQn) & 0x1FUL));
    }
}
```

It contains no `__DMB()` (and also no `__DSB()` nor `__ISB()`), so if I enable interrupt X, and then enable interrupt Y with no barrier between the operations-

```
NVIC_EnableIRQ(X); /* Note: __NVIC_EnableIRQ is defined as NVIC_EnableIRQ */
NVIC_EnableIRQ(Y);
```

Is it promised that the HW will not re-order memory accesses and will enable interrupt X before interrupt Y (lets assume that the compiler does implement function as inline)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it promised that the HW will enable interrupt X before interrupt Y

Yes. The compiler must not optimize the write accesses or change the order - the ISER is declared `volatile` in CMSIS header.

Note that unlike its larger conterparts the Cortex-M0+ does not have a write buffer.

Comment: Is it promised because there is no write buffer? i.e does re-ordering means write buffer? if not, they how does write buffer relates to that?

Comment: @user2162550 the bridge write buffer can reduce the number of wait states needed and it does not change the operation order. It affects the consecutive operations if the relay on the result of the write which may not be completed yet.

Comment: "The compiler must not optimize …" - That's not related to the address space nor is is enforced by the function call (it's actually either an `inline` function or a macro, check the CMSIS header), but simply by the accessed objects being declared `volatile`. This is a standard type qualifier. And even with a write buffer, this works well. there is no extra measure required for Cortex-M3/4/7 either.

Comment: Nevertheless, other registers in this region **do** require an extra barrier, although not necessarily `DMB`. For instance the MPU, although I have to admit I'm not sure the M0(+) allowes for one.

Answer (score 0):

Order is guaranteed but nothing else. Imagine the situation: you have entered the interrupt handler and disable the interrupt as the last instruction. If you have the pending interrupts waiting to be served, so there is no guarantee that yo will not enter the interrupt handler again. To prevent it you need to leave enough time before leaving the interrupt routine, read back the written value or use a barrier.

What barrier instruction to use is the very interesting question. It is not possible to answer it in couple of words.

Here is the [link](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.genc007826/Barrier_Litmus_Tests_and_Cookbook_A08.pdf) to the interesting article which covers the topic, and some [information](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0321a/BIHEADII.html) about the write buffers

Comment: Or use the `DSB` instruction.

Comment: @Olaf - It is in my answer: `or use the barrier`

Comment: That would imply using the `DMB` instruction mentioned in the question. But that is not the correct one, because it does not wait until the write is completed. `DSB` does.

Comment: @Olaf - I do not agree. You need to use the correct one depending on the circumstances. I did not write the instruction intentionally as the question is more general and the NVIC was given as an example.

Comment: Ok, I was following the particular example in the question and your answer which does not cover the other registers. If you mean this more generally, it would be better to be very clear about it, at least not use the definite article,

Comment: Added some external links explaining the barriers and write buffers

Comment: Thanks. I made a small (but imo relevant) change. Feel free to rollback if you disagree.